# Is there a conflict between Pythin gi module and OSX Catalina?

Tags: python, macos-catalina, pygobject

I'm very new to Python and was trying to run a demo program. I'm getting the " no gi module found" error. I've been researching this and I've tried the remedies offered. The module is missing and repeated attempts to install have all failed. I've had a few surprises with other software since I've acquired a new MacBook running OSX Catalina and I'm wondering if there is a connection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO.

The reason I was getting the behavior I describes was that the gi module is not present in the installation of python that I was using, namely the factory installation on my new MacBook. I was aware that python 2 came installed on Macs. Using Homebrew, I installed python3 thinking I had to in order to get into python programming.
Using "which python" in Terminal, I found a python3 installation in /usr/bin/python3. I could find no 'gi' module in this installation and it is version 3.7.3. Using "which python3" I found a python3 alias in /usr/local/bin/python3. There is a 'gi' module with that one and it is version 3.7.7 with the original file python3.7 located in the Cellar of Homebrew.
I confirmed interactively that running this version DID NOT generate the error:

```
SMMac3:~-> python3
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 23 2020, 10:54:01) 
[Clang 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>> exit
```

So I added the following lines to the .zshrc file:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
alias python3=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

And I no longer get the 'module not found' error. :)

Now I have a new problem which I will ask about in a separate question...